# Extrude Acc (Gene ID or accession number) from a fasta file

Tags: regex, bioinformatics, gsub, fasta

What does `".gb\\|(.*)\\|.*","\\1` in the function *gsub* mean?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

If you have a single FASTA sequence in the file you can solve the problem by reading the first line of the file and then split it by the pipe character `|`.

If you have multiple sequences then you can read the first character for each line and look for the `>` character.

Here is a code example in Python. If you need another ID then you can change the index.

```
with open('AE004437.faa') as fh:
    header_line = fh.readline()
    ids = header_line.split('|')
    gene_ids = ids[3]
```